# How to add in a Count in the sub Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have to count in the sub query. I want to add this to the subquery.
I am getting a fail when I add this line to the sub query:
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT v.Department_descr), v.Patient_Number, b.patient_name FROM vwGenVouchInfo v) as pat_dept

---

```sql
SELECT *
FROM vwGenVouchInfo v
WHERE v.Patient_Number=b.Patient_Number
  AND v.Voucher_Primary_Diagnosis_Code  IN ('Z00.129', 'Z00.00') )
ORDER BY voucher_primary_diagnosis_code
```

I want to get a result that will have the patient which department they went to the most times. I am not sure how to add this in. I want pat_dept to hold the dept the patient went to the most times besides the dental dept.

```
SELECT distinct
    a.voucher_primary_diagnosis_code,
   a.Patient_Number
,   b.Patient_Name, b.patient_home_phone, patient_age
FROM vwGenVouchInfo a 
LEFT JOIN vwGenPatInfo b ON a.Patient_Number=b.Patient_Number
WHERE
    a.Department_Descr = 'Dental'
and a.Voucher_Service_Date >= '2015-01-01'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    -- This subquery looks at other vouchers of the same patient.

    -- 
    SELECT *
    FROM vwGenVouchInfo v
    WHERE v.Patient_Number=b.Patient_Number
      AND v.Voucher_Primary_Diagnosis_Code  IN ('Z00.129', 'Z00.00') )
ORDER BY voucher_primary_diagnosis_code
```

Comment: About the error. If you use a subquery then use aliases where needed. For example `select * from (select 1) q;` gives an error, while `select * from (select 1 as myvalue) q` doesn't. So a function like count needs an alias in a subquery.

Comment: even i just try the count statement i got all errors Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'vwGenVouchInfo.Patient_Number' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "b.patient_name" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "b.patient_number" could not be bound.

Comment: In almost all major database types, when you use an aggregate function like COUNT then that basically means it's grouping by.  And then any column in the SELECT (excluding those in the aggregate functions) also needs to be in the GROUP BY part. Look at what @Sid said in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need this in the subquery, you will have to put all the necessary columns one by one along with the count and then group by the same columns.